# copy after specific words and past after specific words

Tags: linux, sed, copy-paste

I want to do copy and paste task in easy way. I had a file which has over 3000 lines. How can I do in linux?

text file

```
#: Bib Field 111
where liblibrarian = "MAIN ENTRY--MEETING NAME";
update  marc_subfield_structure set liblibrarian = "TEMEL GİRİŞ--TOPLANTI ADI", libopac = 

#: Bib Sub 111 f
where liblibrarian = "Date of a work";
update  marc_subfield_structure set liblibrarian = "Eserin tarihi", libopac = 

#: Bib Sub 111 k
where liblibrarian = "Form subheading";
update  marc_subfield_structure set liblibrarian = "Alt başlık biçimlendir", libopac = 

#: Bib Sub 111 l
where liblibrarian = "Language of a work";
update  marc_subfield_structure set liblibrarian = "Eserin dili", libopac = 

#: Bib Sub 111 n
where liblibrarian = "Number of part/section/meeting";
update  marc_subfield_structure set liblibrarian = "Parça/bölüm/toplantı sayısı", libopac =
```

I want

```
update  marc_subfield_structure set liblibrarian = "Toplantı yeri", libopac = "Toplantı yeri" where liblibrarian = "Location of meeting";
update  marc_subfield_structure set liblibrarian = "Relator kodu", libopac = "Relator kodu" where liblibrarian = "Relator code";
update  marc_subfield_structure set liblibrarian = "Eserin adı", libopac = "Eserin adı" where liblibrarian = "Title of a work";
update  marc_subfield_structure set liblibrarian = "Relator terim", libopac = "Relator terim" where liblibrarian = "Relator term";
```

Comment: It's not clear which part are you copying and where are you pasting.

Comment: I want to copy 'where ....' part and paste to the end of 'update ' part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can do that easily with some other tool like awk or sed. But I think it could also be done by, the following:

1. Create a file that only contains the 'where liblibrarian ..' part by the following command:

   `grep 'where liblibrarian' <file> > first_file`
2. Create a file that only contains the 'update  marc_subfield_structure..' part:

   `grep 'update  marc_subfield_structure' <file> > second_file`
3. Now you have two files where each line contains part of the final like that you would like to build. So you have just to paste them column-wise by using the following command (you can adjust the separator to your needs).

   `paste second_file first_file | column -s $'\t' -t`

So this last command will paste the lines by inserting the separator between them.

Comment: Example: 
where liblibrarian = "Number of part/section/meeting";
update  marc_subfield_structure set liblibrarian = "Parça/bölüm/toplantı sayısı"
can it  be this result?
update  marc_subfield_structure set liblibrarian = "Parça/bölüm/toplantı sayısı" where liblibrarian = "Number of part/section/meeting";

Comment: If understood correctly your requirements the above procedure should work